# How to visualize Net Promoter Score (NPS) using Kibana?

Tags: kibana

I want to visualize [NPS](https://www.netpromoter.com/know) (Net Promoter Score) score. The data is very simple, consisting of answers ranging from 0 to 10. Visualizing the answers as such is very simple, but I also want to visualize NPS as time series.

Calculating NPS is simple: `(promoters - detractors) / answers_total * 100`, where

- Promoter: answer=9~10
- Detractor: answer=0~6

Not that difficult calculation, but I can't find a way to do it using Kibana.

Only information I could find was this: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-calculate-net-promoter-score-and-display-in-kibana/51095/8

Writing a plugin is out of question. Modifying the data stored to Elasticsearch is possible.

How should/could I visualize NPS using Kibana?

Comment: If possible at all, then most likely with Timelion: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/timelion.html It is a powerful tool/aggregation language to combine multiple values.